# Batch script not processing remaining of the file after the goto step

Tags: batch-file

I have batch file that writes to the text file with the records. Each of this record needs to be processed from the file. For example if `Name` == `KD` then go to step 1 else continue with the next steps.

The issue after it goes to step 1, it exits the file. I need to come back to the next record to continue processing with `DF`. I did add label to the section to come back but it keeps processing only `KD` record.

Text file example:

```
Line Name Container
1    KD   123
2    DF   657
```

Code:

```
set txtfilepath=C:\Temp\Test.txt
set /a cnt=0
for /f %%a in ('type "%txtfilepath%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a cnt=%%a
echo %txtfilepath% has %cnt% lines

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3,4,5* delims=,] " %%a in ('find /v /n "" ^<   %txtfilepath%') do (

    echo.%%b - this displays variable fine.
    if %%b==DF (
        set result=true
    )  else (
        goto donotexecute
    )
    echo I am in true loop.

    :donotexecute
    echo i am in do not import loop

)
:Done
```

So the code goes in the `donotexecute` label and then I have no way to go back to my initial for loop to continue with the next line in the text file.

Comment: If you include a sample of your batch file we may be able to, at least, understand which OS you are talking about, and perhaps also understand what your question is.

Comment: Thanks for your response, took sometime to format the code. Apologies foe edits... So the code goes in the donotexecute label and then I have no way to go back to my initial for loop to continue with the next line in the txt file

Comment: Don't use `goto` it will break out of any enclosing loops.

Comment: Remove `else (
        goto donotexecute
    )`, or consider replacing `goto` with `call`ing a function. See http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `set /a` (evaluate arithmetic expression) if you just want to assign a value to an environment variable.

Environment variables are always of type string. On an arithmetic expression each number specified directly or hold by an environment variable is converted temporarily to a 32-bit signed integer for evaluation of the expression and the integer result is finally converted back to a string stored in the specified environment variable. So much faster is assigning the number string directly to the environment variable.

Second, Windows command processor does not support labels within a **FOR** loop. You need to use subroutines.

```
@echo off
set "txtfilepath=C:\Temp\Test.txt"

rem Don't know why the number of lines in the files must be determined first?
set "cnt=0"
for /F %%a in ('type "%txtfilepath%" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "" /v /c') do set "cnt=%%a"
echo %txtfilepath% has %cnt% lines.

for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-5* delims=,] " %%a in ("%txtfilepath%") do (
    if "%%b" == "DF" (
        call :ProcessDF "%%c"
    ) else if "%%b" == "KD" (
        call :ProcessKD "%%c"
    )
)

echo Result is: %result%

rem Exit processing of this batch file. This command is required because
rem otherwise the batch processing would continue unwanted on subroutine.
goto :EOF


rem This is the subroutine for name DF.

:ProcessDF
echo Processing DF ...
set "result=true"
echo Container is: %~1
goto :EOF

rem The command above exits subroutine and batch processing continues
rem on next line below the command line which called this subroutine.


rem This is the subroutine for name KD.

:ProcessKD
echo Processing KD ...
echo Container is: %~1
rem Other commands to process.
goto :EOF
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `type /?`

`exit /B` could be also used everywhere where `goto :EOF` is used as this is exactly the same. Run in a command prompt window `exit /?` for details. Sometimes on larger batch files it makes sense to use for example `exit /B` where used to exit processing of batch file and `goto :EOF` where used to just exit a subroutine.

Comment: Thanks this helps.. I am counting the no of lines to understand how long to run the process. Also, can you help me how can I use the variable within the subroutine like I want to use %%b in my ProcessDF routine

Comment: The demo code demonstrates how to pass 1 or more loop variables as arguments from main loop to subroutine where they can be accessed with `%1`, `%2`, etc. See help of command `call`. You could of course assign the string of a loop variable first to an environment variable, then call the subroutine and use the environment variable in subroutine.